# How can i find my vanilla gift card's cvv if it has been scratched off

Tags: visa

I paid for a gift card, but the cvv was scratched off. Can I find out my card code number, or get a replacement card? How?

Comment: Take it and your receipt back to where you got it and ask for one that's legal?

Comment: @keshlam Don't be so quick to accuse. You can damage scratch-off obscured numbers if you're not careful or they did a bad job on the card.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. Never seen it happen, but not impossible. Proper response is still to ask whomever you got it from to replace it; if they were legit this should be possible. The store it's for may also be willing to do so, once they check the account and confirm it is unused.

Answer (score 3):

Credit cards have two CVV numbers, the number printed on the card and the number stored on the mag stripe.  So, just go to a brick-and-mortar store and use your Visa card to buy a new gift card.  Many stores refuse to accept gift cards for gift cards, though possibly they'll make an exception for a Visa card.  If they won't make an exception, just spend it instead. The printed CVV is only needed for online purchases.